# discord.py get channel id from on_raw_reaction_add/remove payload

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I have this `on_raw_reaction_add` payload, and I want to get the channel id of the payload. Is there a way to do it, and if so, how? Code is down below:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  try:
    if payload.member.bot:
        pass
    else:
        #code
  except Exception as e:
      await payload.channel.send(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [channel_id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=raw%20reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.channel_id) attribute to get the id of the channel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out

Comment: How do I get the channel ID though? (Sorry I'm bad at discord.py)

Comment: This will give you the channel id.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what "This" means? I don't understand.

Comment: Doing `payload.channel_id` will return the id of the channel that the reaction happened in.